# Scrape and parse the courses using requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm building the schedule for my next semester. I wanted to be more efficient so I'm trying to scrape my university's page to extract all of the courses and their prerequisites. I use Python with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.

I have some trouble to extract the list of prerequisites that are must and prerequisites that are recommended. Example:

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- ... -->
    <p>
        <img src="gifs/triangle.jpg" width="5" height="10" alt="" border="0" /> Must: The courses
        <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12345.htm" target="_blank">Linear Algebra 101</a>,
        <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12346.htm" target="_blank">Calculus 101</a> (‏12346‎)‏<span class="heara"><a href="#remarks">2</a></span> and one of 
        <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12347.htm" target="_blank">Introduction to Statistics and Probability of Science</a>, <a href="DOMAIN/courses/11231.htm" target="_blank">Probability and Introduction to Computer Science Statistics</a>,
        <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12348.htm" target="_blank">Probability theory</a>. Recommended: <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12349‎.htm" target="_blank">Calculus 102</a> (‏12349‎)‏.
        <span class="heara"><a href="#remarks">3 </a></span>
    </p>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

In that case the content is:

> Must: The courses Linear Algebra 101, Calculus 101 (‏12346‎)‏**2** and one of Introduction to Statistics and Probability of Science, Probability and Introduction to Computer Science Statistics, Probability theory. Recommended: Calculus 102 (‏12349‎)‏. 3

A few notes:

- In that case `Linear Algebra 101` and `Calculus 101` are must. Also one of `Introduction to Statistics and Probability of Science, Probability and Introduction to Computer Science Statistics, Probability theory`.
- Recommended: `Calculus 102`.
- Note that some of the courses are with a number and some are don't (like `Calculus 101`).
- Note that there is a `#remarks` (in our case the bold number 2).

I'm trying to create a dict, something like:

```
{
  "must_courses": [
    "12345",
    "12346"
  ],
  "must_one_of": [
    [
      "12347",
      "11231",
      "12348"
    ]
  ],
  "recommended": [
    "12349"
  ]
}
```

But for some reason it's really hard to parse it because:

- First of all, there are a few `<p>` in the "content" `div` and since the `<p>` does not have a class/id, it's really hard to find the right `<p>`. The `<p>` number isn't fixed. Usually it's the second or the third `<p>`
- Some of the course names do not have the course number in their name so the number should be extracted from the `<a href=$url`.
- I need to check if its in the right format - It could start with `Must`, is could start with `Recommended`. It also could have the "and one of" courses.

What I tried:

```
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
content_div = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'content'})
p_sections = content_div.find_all('p')
for index, p_section in enumerate(p_sections):
    if index == 3:
        # Sometimes its index 2 and sometimes its index 3
        # Tried to use: p_section.text
```

Even if I know which index it's the right `<p>`, I still don't know how to parse the line.

A few examples:
Example 1:

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- ... -->
    <p>
        <img src="gifs/triangle.jpg" width="5" height="10" alt="" border="0" /> Must: The course <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12346.htm" target="_blank">Calculus 101</a> (‏12346‎)‏.
        <span class="heara"><a href="#remarks">2</a></span>
    </p>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

content:

> Must: The course Calculus 101 (‏12346‎)‏. **2**

Example 2:

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- ... -->
    <p><img src="gifs/triangle.jpg" width="5" height="10" alt="" border="0" />
 Recommended: The course <a href="DOMAIN/courses/04101.htm" target="_blank">Combinatorics</a>.</p>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Content:

> Recommended: The course Combinatorics.

But I just need one example on how to parse it "right" and I think I could play around with the regex (I think that's the way to do it?) to parse different lines. Added the examples to make it easier to understand the task I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for the first example. Find the content you are trying to scrape:

```
html = """\
<div id="content">
    <!-- ... -->
    <p>
        <img src="gifs/triangle.jpg" width="5" height="10" alt="" border="0" /> Must: The courses
        <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12345.htm" target="_blank">Linear Algebra 101</a>,
        <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12346.htm" target="_blank">Calculus 101</a> (‏12346‎)‏<span class="heara"><a href="#remarks">2</a></span> and one of 
        <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12347.htm" target="_blank">Introduction to Statistics and Probability of Science</a>, <a href="DOMAIN/courses/11231.htm" target="_blank">Probability and Introduction to Computer Science Statistics</a>,
        <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12348.htm" target="_blank">Probability theory</a>. Recommended: <a href="DOMAIN/courses/12349‎.htm" target="_blank">Calculus 102</a> (‏12349‎)‏.
        <span class="heara"><a href="#remarks">3 </a></span>
    </p>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
content = soup.find(attrs={'id': 'content'})
```

Extract unwanted span tags with class name `heara`:

```
[unwanted.extract() for unwanted in content.find_all('span', class_="heara")]
```

Grab all urls from href tags to form ids:

```
raw_urls = [each['href'] for each in content.find_all('a')]
ids = [re.findall(r'\d+', url)[0] for url in raw_urls]
# -> ['12345', '12346', '12347', '11231', '12348', '12349']
```

Grab all text inside `a` tags and inside content itself. Split content text by keywords, such as `and one of`, `Recommended` to compare with the words inside `a` tags:

```
raw_text = [each.text for each in content.find_all('a')]

# grab texts by their importance
raw_must_take = content.text.strip().split('and one of')[0]
raw_must_one_of = content.text.strip().split('and one of')[1].split('Recommended')[0]
raw_recommended = content.text.strip().split('Recommended')[1]
```

Compare each word in a tag with corresponded strings to form clean courses:

```
clean_must_take = [each for each in raw_text if each in raw_must_take]
clean_must_one_of = [each for each in raw_text if each in raw_must_one_of]
clean_recommended = [each for each in raw_text if each in raw_recommended]
"""
['Linear Algebra 101', 'Calculus 101']
['Introduction to Statistics and Probability of Science', 'Probability and Introduction to Computer Science Statistics', 'Probability theory']
['Calculus 102']
"""
```

Find the ids range according to the length of each clean list, and form dictionary:

```
must_take_range = [0, len(clean_must_take)]
must_one_of_range = [len(clean_must_take), len(clean_must_take) + len(clean_must_one_of)]
recommended_range = [len(clean_must_take) + len(clean_must_one_of), len(ids)]


d = defaultdict(list)
[d["must_take"].append(ids[i]) for i in range(*must_take_range)]
[d["must_one_of"].append(ids[i]) for i in range(*must_one_of_range)]
[d["recommended"].append(ids[i]) for i in range(*recommended_range)]
```

Final result would look like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'must_take': ['12345', '12346'], 'must_one_of': ['12347', '11231', '12348'], 'recommended': ['12349']})
```

Imports:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict
```

PS: I know this is not the best solution but it works :)